# Why html modifying waits for the end of loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why I can see alerts before end of loop, but other html-related commands waits for the end?
How to change it in main flow? Requests is lasts long.

I need synchronous requests because some reasons.

```js
$('.task-progress div').each(function () {
        let div = $(this),
        id = $(this).data('id');

        div.append('...');
        alert('start '+id);
        div.css('color', 'red');
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', '/#'+id, false);
        xhr.onload = function() {
                div.text('xhr.responseText');
                alert('end '+id);
        };
        xhr.send();

    })
```

```html
<div class="task-progress">
    <div data-id="234242">234242</div>
    <div data-id="234543">234543</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdp4gc61/

Comment: You're using synchronous  XHR. What you are experiencing is precisely the bad behavior that makes synchronous requests such a bad idea.

Comment: If the server is slow, that's even more of a reason not to use synchronous XHR.

Comment: And perhaps you should only make one request for all data and change the logic of this around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to your question of why `alert()` happens immediately but DOM updates seem to be delayed until your code finishes running: the DOM is actually updated immediately when you store something in it, but the browser does not re-render the affected DOM elements until all JavaScript finishes executing, i.e. when your function returns.

If the browser re-rendered the page immediately after each bit of DOM manipulation, you would see each individual change briefly, for example in the code `$div.append('...').css('color', 'red');` you might see the '...' appear for a moment before it turned red.

`alert()` is a very special case. It does not use the DOM and does not rely on the browser re-rendering the page. `alert()` should be rarely or never used in modern JavaScript code.

If you need to make multiple requests and sequence them one after the other, the correct way is to use *asynchronous* XHR and send each request after the previous one completes. It could look something like this:

```
function updateAllProgress() {
    const $divs = $('.task-progress div');
    let index = 0;

    function updateNextProgress() {
        if( index >= $divs.length ) return;  // done

        const $div = $($divs[index]);
        const id = $div.data('id');
        $div.append('...').css('color', 'red');
        $.get( '/#'+id, function( data ) {
            $div.text( data );
            ++index;
            updateNextProgress();
        });
    }
}
```

You could also add a short delay between requests if that is desired, just change the `updateNextProgress();` call at the end to `setTimeout( updateNextProgress, 1000 );` or the like.

Also pay attention to charlietfl's note that `'#'` in the URL is probably not the right thing to use. Normally you would expect to see `'?'` used in a URL like this.

Comment: Thank you! Much better idea.
And # just for jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) ajax method that would make this all much simpler and make requests in parallel

```
$('.task-progress div').each(function() {
  let div = $(this), id = div.data('id');
  div.load('/somePath/' + id);    
});
```

Note url with `#` in it isn't right for making remote request